# Angular-cli + electron import typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

Good afternoon, I am unable to import the electron module in my ts. I have the following error: Cannot find module 'electron'.
My structure:

- Project

  - covarage
  - dist
  - electron

    - main.js
    - package.json
  - src

    - app

      - components...
    - assest
    - environmentes
    - services

      - services
    - index.html
    - main.ts
    - polyfills.ts
    - tsconfig.json
    - typings.d.ts
  - angular-cli.json
  - karma.conf.js
  - package.json
  - protractor.conf.js
  - tslint.json

main.js electron:

```
const electron = require('electron')

const app = electron.app

const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)

  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  mainWindow.setMenu(null);

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null;
  })
}

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
});

app.on('activate', function () {

  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
});

const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain

ipc.on('get-app-path', function (event) {
  event.sender.send('got-app-path', app.getAppPath())
})
```

My index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>X</title>
  <script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    var electron = require('electron');
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body style="padding-top: 70px;">
  <app-root>
    loading...
  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

My import in component:

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
```

I have tested:
typings.d.ts:

```
declare var System: any;
declare var electron: any;
```

declared in script index.html:

```
var electron = require('electron');
```

and component:

```
electron.ipcRenderer.on('got-app-path', function (event, path) {
    ...
});
```

nothing happens...

Any suggestion? grateful!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by declaring:

```
<script>
var electron = require('electron');
</script>
```

in index.html and typings.d.ts:

```
declare var electron: any;
```

My Component:

```
const {ipcRenderer} = electron;
console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping'));
```

Part of the problem was the async!